# PlaceAutocomplete got unknown status code: 9000

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-places-api

I reused the code from Google PlaceAutocomplete sample project by Android team.

I used different key for each project (also enabled Google Places for Android in google console).

When I build and run the sample project, it was working without problem.

However, when i run it from my app, sometimes it's working, other times I got unknown status code: 9000 (from status.toString()).

I got this on the console:

```
04-08 01:15:39.331  16148-10791/? W/Places﹕ f.a:633: gLocReplyElement unsuccessful status: 1

04-08 01:15:39.332  16148-10791/? W/Places﹕ f.a:660: gPlaceQueryResult unsuccessful responseCode: 26

04-08 01:15:39.339  10558-11608/com.travelapp.karet W/karet﹕ Error getting autocomplete prediction API call: Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 9000, resolution=null}
```

It's very strange, so when I type s,i (start suggesting places),n,g . So when I reached the fourth letter I occasionally got this error.

So the only part that was different was only the int value clientId that I passed to mgoogleApiClient.enableAutoManage()

The sample project use 0, while my project use 9993938838939 (random number). -I'm not sure what value should I put here (it rejected number that's already used by other app)

Other than that, the codes was no different (only that I put the googleclient variable on Activity, but the actual Autocomplete implementation on a Fragment)

Please help.

Comment: I got this on the console:[br]

`04-08 01:15:39.331  16148-10791/? W/Places﹕ f.a:633: gLocReplyElement unsuccessful status: 1`

`04-08 01:15:39.332  16148-10791/? W/Places﹕ f.a:660: gPlaceQueryResult unsuccessful responseCode: 26`

`04-08 01:15:39.339  10558-11608/com.travelapp.karet W/karet﹕ Error getting autocomplete prediction API call: Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 9000, resolution=null}`

Comment: Did you enable Android's places API, or the general one? I ran into this problem because I had enabled the wrong API.

Comment: FWIW I'm seeing the same issue.

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same problem and was able to solve it. There are 3 things to be done in the manifest file to make the demo work:

1- Add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`, If not already there.

2- Replace `ADD_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE` with your api key. You can generate an api key by using this link: [Google Places Sign Up](https://developers.google.com/places/android/signup).

3- Add Android application package of demo app to the list of allowed apps like this: `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete`

To add to the list of allowed apps, visit the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project/). Then select the project you're working on. On the left hand side, click on the "APIs & auth" link, and below that click on the "Credentials" link. After that, click on the "Edit allowed Android applications" button. Now you can enter application package of the demo app e.g. `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;com.example.google.playservices.placecomplete` in the text box.

**Note:** XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX = YOUR SHA1 certificate fingerprint

Comment: Can't speak for OP, but I've verified all those things and I'm still seeing the error.

Comment: @dpassage Step 3 is very important as this is the sole reason for this error, You have to add your machine's SHA fingerprint, from which you are compiling and running the sample along with application package defined in manifest file!

Comment: @dpassage Also make sure that you have enabled the places api :)

Comment: Yup, did that too. What's become weird is that the 9000's are now intermittent.

Comment: guys, I already solve this problem.
I don't understand what was the solution, after I added second device in the Google API console credentials, the app works like charm, even in the first device.

i assume this is google api console credentials's bug?

Comment: i face same problem as u.. you find any exact solutions.. if yes then please help me..

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that you have added the required values to your AndroidManifest.xml

Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

Meta-Data:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="ADD_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE"/>
```

Take a look at the Sample AndroidManifest.xml [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/blob/master/PlaceComplete/Application/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)

Comment: already added that in the first place. 
I still got error with the same code

Comment: This works but lacks an important note. You should only use one API KEY in your manifest file.

Answer (score 2):

```
Please ensure the folowing.

1. The package name given in console registration page must be same as that of actvity/fragment we are using. ie; if are using this auto search button inside com.example.rajeesh.UI.fragements.SearchFragment, 
then inside console registration page  package name should be 
com.example.rajeesh.UI.fragements
This is different from the package name we given in manifest file.

2. Inside manifest please  change 
  <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="@string/google_maps_api_key" />
to

      <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="@string/google_maps_api_key" />


3. Enable Google Places API for Android in console page.
```